# Web api add custom header for NotFound()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In a WebApi Controller I return this: `return NotFound();`

How can I add a custom header to this?

I"ve seen solution with FilterAttribute but those have effect on the whole api.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `HttpResponseMessage` then add headers as you needed then create `ResponseMessageResult`:

```
var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
responseMessage.Headers.Add("YourHeader", "Value");
return ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
```